# Ioncube HTML encoder issue

Tags: ioncube

Using the encoder it displays this message

```
<!--

Page protected by ionCube - HTML/JavaScript Encoder
Copyright (c) 2003 RWJD.Com and ionCube Ltd.  All Rights Reserved.

Any analysis of this  source code,  embedded data  or file by any means and by
any entity whether human or otherwise  to including but without  limitation to
discover details  of internal operation, to  reverse  engineer, to  de-compile
object code, or to modify  for the purposes  of modifying behavior or scope of
their usage is forbidden.

-->
```

Is it possible to change that message to include a policy? Like edit that comment? Its really annoying because it needs to be changed to my written one that my lawyer wrote..

Answer (score 1):

This might be better asked in the [ionCube Helpdesk](http://ioncu.be/S), but that said, I can advise as I am associated with ionCube. Modification of the paragraph below the copyright message would be permitted in this case, however as the obfuscation is generated dynamically at runtime and as the script does not have a feature for providing a replacement legal notice, this isn't entirely trivial. You could try installing an output handler after the obfuscator is included so as to catch the output produced by the obfuscator. Your handler could then do a search and and replace on the output.

Please be aware of the hopefully obvious limitations to client side protection and trying to hide HTML and Javascript in this way. The obfuscator, which was donated by an early ionCube customer, is quite clever and a free example of an encoded file, and a decade ago also very effective. As browsers evolved, plugins and then native features for DOM browsing became standard making it easy to regenerate HTML from the DOM, i.e. after any deobfuscation has run.

While most users to a site would not be aware of how to recreate HTML in this way, it's equally the case that they're not going to care about doing so; most visitors just want a site to work, be responsive, and not have navigation and other features broken by tricks such as right click disabling. Those who would want to steal HTML would know how to via DOM inspection, and they would also know how to access data from browser caches, would take screenshots if necessary to steal images rather than need right-click "save image", and so on. There are techniques to defeat some of those approaches, but at a cost to every visitor that's not probably worth it. Also note that obfuscation in this way should ensure *exclusion* of pages from Google, just in case that matters.

That said and noting IANAL, protecting the HTML with the obfuscator may have benefits from a legal perspective as the HTML cannot in general be discovered unwittingly or by mistake, and if someone did steal content, they would have had to have tried, albeit perhaps not that hard.

Hope this helps!